# Can I send data from a $scope to an var array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a dynamic add/remove fields that use AngularJs and I wanna send that data to my Firebase database. I don't know how I can do that or if it is possible. If it isn't, could someone tell me how can I send the data from `$scope` to and var array or give me an alternative?

Here is some code:

```
<td><input type="text" ng-model="choice.Locatie" name="Locatie" placeholder="Locatie" ></td>
<td><input type="text" ng-model="choice.Nr" name="Nr" placeholder="Nr" style="width: 40px;"></td>
<td><input type="text" ng-model="choice.Greutate" name="Greutate" placeholder="Greutate"></td>
<td><input type="text" ng-model="choice.Referinta" name="Referinta" placeholder="Referinta"></td>
<td><input type="text" ng-model="choice.Observatii" name="Observatii" placeholder="Observatii"></td>
```

And this is the script for dynamic add/remove fields:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.choices = [{id: 'pas1'}];
    $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
        var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
        $scope.choices.push({'id':'pas'+newItemNo});
    };

    $scope.removeChoice = function() {
        var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
        $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
    };
});
```

Firebase:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.5/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "api-key",
    authDomain: "example.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://example.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "example.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "0000000000"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

Comment: You can pass `$scope.choices` itself. Any issues you faced by passing it?

Comment: Can you create a plunkr for this problem statement ?

Comment: @Developer i don't know how to pass it .

Comment: @KarthikVU here is a link : http://jsfiddle.net/9tk0qpng/2/

Comment: @icecold2 : Where is your service which posts data to firebase ?

Comment: @Developer Could you please give me an example of how could i send $scope.choices to firebase data?

Comment: check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: @JAG I don't know how could I write from $scope.choices to firebase. Variables and data I know how to write.

Comment: how about this http://codepen.io/Angularjschile/pen/RNxLWV

Comment: @JAG Thank you very much. You can post your answer.

Comment: @JAG I have one more question. Do i need to add a button for saving what i edited?